# Enable Call recording

Tags: call-recording

Google has blocked call recording in my country. If I root my Samsung S20 and put in a custom ROM will I be able to use call recording apps?

Comment: To say that "Google" blocked call recording seems to make the action sound arbitrary. Is it in compliance with your national, state, or local government regulation regarding recordings? We can only surmise your location based on the only personalized data you provide - your user name - and you do not state your government in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to enable call recording if you have root access.

Comment: specifying the steps to do so (assuming root access) would be quite helpful here!

Comment: Download any call recording app (skvalex, true phone, etc), grant root access to it or refer to app manual, enjoy (: